# Open library in Powerbuilder 7

Tags: powerbuilder

I'm new on Powerbuilder, I'm trying to edit an exist project it was built using Powerbuilder 7 but I have some library do not open and I get message "Could not open application 'pathmainlibrary' in 'C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\SAD\pathmain.pbl'".

Comment: PB7 is pretty old; peer experience may be sparse. A couple of clarifying questions. When you say "edit a project", do you mean edit code in the application in general, or trying to change a project object (provides compilation directives) specifically? Do you have the "library path" (list of PBLs in order that they are to be searched for objects) and have you defined this path to your IDE (in PB7, this was stored in an INI tied to the IDE)?

Comment: @Terry I'm trying to edit code in general, and I have the list of PBLs when I click on list of libraries I can see project libraries, but I defined this path in INI file.

Comment: In this library I have two application the first one is "pathmain" I can open it and the second one is "pathmainlibrary" this one I can't open it but when I search for some variable I have true result.

Comment: My first advice would be to avoid editing the INI, and define the path in the IDE; my memory doesn't go back to the last century well, so you might have to explore frame menus and context menus for something called "Library Path". Note that when you open a different application, you'll have to redefine the library path, which is app-specific. In many cases, having a valid library path is necessary for opening objects.

Answer (score 1):

First try to move all your SAD application content to a folder like c:\dummy.

Then verify you've at least:

- One PBW file (ascii)
- One PBT file (ascii)
- One PBL file (binary)

Now edit the first file (notepad is enough), it should contain the name of your PBT file;
edit the pbt file, it should contain at least the name of the pbl project file and the library list at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used PB 7 for quite a while, but if I'm not mistaken the workspace/tagret structure (and therefore the .pbw and .pbt files) did not exist before PB 8.
All you need to have is a bunch of .pbl files, and an application object in one of those pbl's/ The library list is a property of the application object.

But again, I haven't used PB7 for a long time!